# Shortest path between raw geo coordinates and a node of a graph

Tags: java, geospatial, shortest-path, dijkstra, pythagorean

I have implemented a simple Dijkstra's algorithm for finding the shortest path on an .osm map with Java.

The pathfinding in a graph which is created from an .osm file works pretty well. But in case the user's current location and/or destination is not a node of this graph (just raw coordinates) how do we 'link' those coordinates to the graph to make pathfinding work?

The simple straightforward solution "find the nearest to the current location node and draw a straight line" doesn't seem to be realistic. What if we have a situation like on the attached picture? (UPD)
[image]

The problem here is that before we start any 'smart' pathfinding algorithms (like Dijkstra's) we 'link' the current position to the graph, but it is just dumb formula (a hypotenuse from Pythagorean theorem)  of finding the nearest node in terms of geographical coordinates and this formula is not 'pathinding' - it can not take obstacles and types of nodes into account.

To paraphrase it - how do we find the shortest path between A and B if B is a node in a graph, and A is not a node?

Have you heard of any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The process you're describing is "[map matching](http://www.google.com/search?q=map%20matching)," and it uses a [spatial index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index) to find the nearest node.

One common approach is to construct a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) that contains all your nodes, then identify the quad that contains your point, then calculate the distance from your point to all nodes in the quad (recognizing that longitudinal degrees are shorter than latitudinal degrees). If there are no nodes in the quad then you progressively expand your search. There are several caveats with quadtrees, but this should at least get you started.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I had to read through all the links you kindly provided. The question: how this 'quadtree method' is different from a plain 'find the nearest node in a certain radius' method? As I understand, if we don't find any nodes in the quad, we should try the next quad (by the way how do we choose from 3 other quads? What is the criteria?). But this is very similar to searching for the nearest node in a certain radius and increasing the radius until the nearest node is found.

Comment: @Kirill - how do you "find the nearest node"? Unless you plan to iterate through all your nodes, you need some way to organize them. A quadtree is one way to organize nodes that are close to each other.

Comment: find the nearest node: we can set a minimum desired 'bounding box', and create a list of all nodes that are located in this box (i.e. their coordinates are inside some 'bounding box'). Then we iterate through the list and calculate the distance (Pythagorean theorem) between our current location and the taken node. Then we choose the node with the minimal distance. The problem here is that we can grow the 'bounding box' until it captures "Nearest to the current position node" from the picture, but not the 'Fence' nodes. I think that the same problem exists for quadtrees.

Comment: @Kirill - I'll ask again: how do you "create a list of all nodes that are located in this box"? Either you iterate all of your nodes to do that, or you find a way to index the nodes. Iteration may be fine if you have a few dozen or a few thousand nodes. In the real world, you have millions of nodes, and it's not an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, I would just ignore the problem and use your suggested algorithm "straight line to nearest node". It is the user's responsibility to be as close as possible to a routable entity. If the first guess you suggested was missleading, user can change the starting position accordingly.

The user who really starts his journey in no man's land hopefully knows the covered area much more than your algorithm. Trust him.

BTW, this is the algorithm that [OpenRouteService](http://www.openrouteservice.org/) and [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com) are using.

If still not convinced, I suggest to use the "shortest straight line that does not cross an obstacle". If this is still not enough, define a virtual grid of say 5mx5m and its diagonals. Than span a shortest path algorithm until you reach a graph-vertex.

Comment: -1. thats not the problem and I am very sure that google/ors does not use this simple algorithm! imagine you are on a street but the start nodes of this street are far away, but another street its start node is close to your position. This often occurs for a highway crossing a smaller street. Then your routing algo will use the wrong starting position

Comment: Right, Google is not snapping to the first/last vertex of a street, but to the closest point of the street. Still it is just catching the closest point "on the road network." Try it out: It even crosses an obstacle like a railway track even for car navigation: https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=42.761634,-89.244869&daddr=42.741024,-89.188914&hl=en&sll=42.755269,-89.232459&sspn=0.024421,0.038581&geocode=FaJ9jAIdOzuu-g%3BFSAtjAIdzhWv-g&dirflg=w&mra=ls&t=m&z=14

Comment: but exactly that was the question: how to get the closest point even if it is on a road

Comment: I thought Kirill is primarily concerned about obstacle avoiding.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat the current location as a node, and connect that node to a few of the nearest nodes in a straight line. GPS applications would consider this straight line as being 'off road', so the cost of this line is very big compared to the other lines between nodes.

However, I didn't see your attached picture, so not sure this is a good solution for you.

Comment: The problem is finding the nearest nodes

Answer (score 0):

Really nice question!

Quad tree is a solution, as you can also index lines/edges into it, not only nodes.

But the problems with this 'naive' approach is that these solutions are memory intensive. E.g. if you already have a very big graph for shortest path calculation then you need the same or more memory for the quad tree (or I was doing something very stupid).

One solution is as follows:

- use an array which is a grid over the used area. I mean you can devide your area into tiles, and per tile you have an array entry with the list of nodes.
- so per array entry you'll have a list of nodes in that tile. For an edge you can just add both nodes to the entry. Take care when there are edges crossing a tile without having its node in this tile. The BresenhamLine algorithm will help here.
- querying: converte the input ala (lat,lon) into a tile number. now get all points from the array entry. Calculate the nearest neighbor of the nodes AND edges to your *point A* using euclidean geometry (which should be fine as long as they are not too far away which is the case for nearest neighbor).

Is this description clear?

**Update**
This is now [implemented](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/storage/Location2IDPreciseIndex.java) in graphhopper!

To get a more memory efficient solution you have to simply exclude identical nodes for one entry (tile).

A bit more complicated technic to reduce mem-usage: if a graph traversal respects the tile bounds you can imagine that the graph is then devided into several sub-graphs for that tile (ie. a graph traversal wouldn't reach the other sub-graph within the tile-bounds). Now you don't need all nodes but only the nodes which lay in a different sub-graph! This will reduce the memory usage, but while querying you need to traverse not only one edge further (like in the current graphhopper implementation)! Because you need to traverse the full tile - i.e. as so long as the tile bounds are not exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

If you have constraints in your path, you should consider using a linear programming formulation of the same shortest path problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Your objective would be to minimize the sum of the distance of each "way" taken between the starting and ending "nodes" defined in your .osm file. Any obstacles would be formulated as constraints. To implement with Java, see the link below.

http://javailp.sourceforge.net/