# How to partition a graph using a quadtree?

Tags: java, graph, partitioning, graph-algorithm, quadtree

I have a program that allows the user to draw vertices and edges on a JFrame of size 1000 by 750. Now I need to use a quadtree to partition the input graph depending on how many vertices there are in a single quadrant. I would really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Additional information:
I have an Edge class which stores: source (vertex), target (vertex) and weight.
I have a Vertex class which stores: name, x-coordinates, y-coordinates, and Edge[] adjacentList.
I also have a Graph class which stores two ArrayLists: edges and vertices.

Comment: How do you want to partition it? Do you cut off the vertices that are in the quadrant with the most vertices?
Anyway, I don't think your problem has all that much to do with graphs. You can do the partition based on the x-y coordinates of the vertices alone.

Comment: I was hoping to define an upper limit on the maximum number of vertices per quadrant so it keeps splitting until it no longer exceeds that threshold. Also each vertex can only belong to exactly one region. Nothing actually gets cut off. For each region I need to run a shortest path algorithm for each vertex in that region and compute edge flags.

Comment: @ jclancy in the end I did go with your method to partition the graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've recently implemented code, that should solve your problem. It's free for download on my recent blog post. Quadtrees for Space Decomposition, Java Implementation http://kirstywilliams.co.uk/blog/2012/08/quadtrees-java-implementation/

Answer (score 1):

Some more quadtree implementations which are both apache licensed:

- [Apache SIS](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/sis/trunk/sis-core/src/main/java/org/apache/sis/storage/QuadTree.java) - no tests, fast, but [several improvements necessary](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SIS-45)
- [GraphHopper](https://github.com/karussell/GraphHopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/de/jetsli/graph/trees/QuadTreeSimple.java) - with tests, less memory consumption but probably a bit slower. The distance calculation is pluggable.

But if you already have a connected graph in memory you can create a much more memory efficient (but also a bit complicated) solution. Parts are implemented [here](https://github.com/karussell/GraphHopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/de/jetsli/graph/storage/Location2IDQuadtree.java), more details available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11881799/194609).

Another [interesting repo](https://github.com/neo4j/graph-collections/tree/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/collections) (but AGPL I think as neo4j itself) with some spatial collections.